# Dimension of an analytic subvariety and Krull dimension of its local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ be a irreducible analytic subvariety, and $x\in X$ an arbitrary point. Suppose that the germ of $X$ is represented by a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,x}$, and set $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}:=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,x}/\mathfrak{p}$. Define the dimension $\operatorname{dim}(X):=\operatorname{dim}(X_{\operatorname{reg}})$ as the dimension of the submanifold of regular part of $X$. Then do we have $$
\operatorname{dim}(X)=\operatorname{dim}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})?
$$(I know this holds for $x\in X_{\operatorname{reg}}.$) This is clear in the algebraic geometric context, but it is more difficult when we involve holomorphic functions. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. This is implied by **Criterion for Purity** from Grauert's and Remmert's *Coherent analytic sheaves* (see p.106):

> **Definition** A complex space $X$ is called *pure dimensional* if
> $$\dim_x X = \dim X \quad \text{for all }x \in X.$$
> A complex space is called *pure dimensional at a point* $x \in X$, if there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U$ is pure dimensional.
>
> **Criterion for purity:** *A complex space $X$ is pure dimensional at all points where $X$ is irreducible.*

They have a slightly different definition of $\dim_x X$, but in 5 §1 (p.95 et seq) they prove $\dim_x X = \dim \mathcal O_x$.